# Filter datetime index by date

Tags: python, pandas

Can you please explain wy this code doesn't work and how to make it work:

```
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=9, freq='T')
dates = index.date
index.loc(dates[0])
```

I tried other solutions like:

```
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=9, freq='T')
dates = pd.to_datetime(index.date)
index.loc(dates[0])
```

As you can see, I want to extract one date from datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

When you create `index`, it is a `DatetimeIndex` object, that does not have the `loc` attribute. The `DatetimeIndex` object does not have indexes as it itself is used as an index. You can access elements just by square brackets as in lists `[]`.

It is not clear what exactly you want to do.

You can use `index[0]` to access first element, or make list, numpy array, or DaraFrame using `.to_list()`, `.to_numpy()`, `.to_frame()' for easyer manipulations.

To extract date from `index`, just `index[0].date()` is enough.

Also when you create `dates`, all dates are the same, as `index` elements are different from each other only by minutes.

First, create a date_rangeby using 5 hours (so we will have several points in one day). The last line will return all indexes from a specific date. You can define any date and write `index.date == your_date` to use it.

```
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100, freq='5H')
dates = index.date
index[index.date == dates[0]]
```

Comment: I want to extract observations with specific date from datetime index. I posted index as exmaple. In real example I have dataframe. But the problem is the same.

Comment: I have added some part, hope its what are you looking for. Use `index[index.date == dates[0]]`  for filtering dates.